# Keep getting Ruby Twitter::Error::Forbidden

Tags: ruby, windows, loops, twitter, status

I'm pulling tweets from a text file and tweeting them in timed intervals. As the first tweet is posted, everything is fine. When its time for the next tweet to post I get an error that reads:

[image]

I got my four keys, but I can always renew them or get new ones...Here is the code I'm using:

```
require 'Twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "..."
  config.consumer_secret = "..."
  config.access_token = "..."
  config.access_token_secret = "..."
end


def repeat_every(interval)
  loop do
    start_time = Time.now
    yield
    elapsed = Time.now - start_time
    sleep([interval - elapsed, 0].max)
  end
end


blog_post = []
tweet_img = []


def post 
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key = "..."
        config.consumer_secret = "..."
        config.access_token = "..."
        config.access_token_secret = "..."
    end
  File.open("tweets.txt") do |line|
    line.each do |item|
      tweets = item
      puts tweets
      client.update("#{tweets}").to_s
      sleep((rand*1800 +900).to_i)
    end
  end
end


repeat_every(81000){
    post
}
```

Comment: It says you are missing a required parameter called "status," have you looked into that?

Comment: Yeah I don't know how to add that parameter...or why...it tweets normally at first.. plus the code that tweets says I use "client.update("text")" in order to tweet. So I thought that would be work. :\ @cantido

Comment: do you know how to add that param? @cantido

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'Twitter'

def repeat_every(interval)
  loop do
    start_time = Time.now
    yield
    elapsed = Time.now - start_time
    sleep([interval - elapsed, 0].max)
  end
end


def post 
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = "xxxx"
      config.consumer_secret = "xxxx"
      config.access_token = "xxxx"
      config.access_token_secret = "xxxx"
    end
  File.open("tweets.txt") do |line|
    line.each_line do |item|
      tweets = item
      puts tweets
      client.update("#{tweets}")
      sleep((rand*10 + 10).to_i)
    end
  end

end


repeat_every(81000){
    post
}
```

Comment: also, Perhaps #{tweets} is over 140 character?

Comment: watch out twitter character limit.

Answer (score 0):

insert this code on the second line

```
OpenSSL :: SSL :: VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL :: SSL :: VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: Add some description rather providing only link to reference.

Comment: Sorry. I not good at English. Do not know well explanation possible.

I thought ssl certificate is not set well.
So, I have disabled the authentication of certificate.

Comment: I have no confidence that has been described well. Do you could understand? And pray that you are transmitted successfully.

Comment: I get a "warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER"  ...whatever that means @rainwont

Comment: and then it does not post the tweet @rainwont

Comment: Is difficult to understand the problem becomes complicated. Let's look at one by one. 1. consumerkey, consumersecretkey, accesstoken, aceestokensecret Do not mistake these? [link](http://apps.twitter.com) 2. What you originally posted itself can be? Specifies the string directly. Do you can post in this? `post.client ("test tweet")` 3. Are you retrieve one row at a time string from accurately file? `File.open ("tweets.txt") do | line | line.each_line do | item | tweets = item puts tweets` I want you to check.　@marriedjane875

Comment: The keys are correct, the original strings are correct and post as they are. Retrieving one row at a time works fine...it prints them in order. I used puts and did not try to tweet from the file so it was displayed in the command prompt. The only issue is "post.client(""test tweet")" << this will not work, and i get an error that reads: '<main>' : undefined method 'client' for #<Twitter::REST::Client:0x000000037b4438> (NoMethodError) @rainwont

Comment: sorry. type miss is `post.client` 　`client.update` is correct.

Comment: yeah i think the problem is the version of Ruby I'm using (Ruby 2.1.5-x64) and the gem, twitter-5.14.0 ...but i'm not sure. it doesn't have this problem in mac. only windows. @rainwont

Comment: this code inserted? `OpenSSL :: SSL :: VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL :: SSL :: VERIFY_NONE` 
And I also use Windows, and although I think for ssl certificate setting is wrong error occurs If you do not insert before connecting this one line to Twitter.　For more information on this link　[link](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/404) 
I because only read Japanese well, the contents of this site can not be explained well. I'm referring to the Japanese site. To say whether, you probably will not to read Japanese site. . .